# PowerShell script to look for number and if greater than send email

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a script that runs a command, reads the output and then if a number is greater than...send an email.

This is the code I have so far -

```
$Output = 'D:\test.data\QueuedJobss.txt'
d:
set-location -Path 'D:\program files\veritas\netbackup\bin\admincmd'
.\bpdbjobs -summary -L > $Output

$Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Matches.Groups[1].Value

if ($Queued -gt 100 ) {
  $MailArgs = @{
        'To'          = 'ab2112@test.com'
        'From'        = 'netbackup@test.com'
        'Subject'     = 'Over 100 Queued Jobs!'
        'Attachments' = $Output
        'Body'        = 'Check Environment'

        'SmtpServer' = 'smtp.us.test.com'
       }
     Send-MailMessage @MailArgs
  }
```

It is currently returning an error -

```
}
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:6 char:81
+ $Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Match.Groups[ <<<< 1].Value
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

The output that it's reading looks like -

```
Summary of jobs on ustestnbma01
Queued:                                1
Waiting-to-Retry:                        0
Active:                           5
Successful:                   25876
Partially Successful:           136
Failed:                         327
Incomplete:                       0
Suspended:                        0
Total:                        26345
```

The row I'm focused on is Queued, that number is followed by a lot of spaces.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PowerShell in particular, but based on other regular expressions that I've seen, the parentheses seem to be used to designate groups.  So since you used the pattern "`Queued: \s+(\d+)`", it looks like you would only have one group in your result set, corresponding to `\d+`.  With that in mind, you should select `Groups[0]` instead of `Groups[1]`.

Comment: Scratch that... Your error message says that the `Groups` array is a "null array".  So this is even simpler than my first guess.  Your pattern was not found, so no `Groups` exists.  Either your pattern is wrong or your input string is wrong.  Either way, you should probably add a condition to check that `Groups` is not null before trying to index into it.

Comment: How should I do that? I know that the pattern is met and still the command isn't working. Does the pattern and the regex cmd look ok based on what output it's reading? See above

Answer (score 1):

Is your code waiting for the job to finish before running - are you sure there is an output for the `select-string` cmdlet at the time that cmdlet runs? Perhaps try to replace with this instead:

```
If (Test-Path $Output)
{
    $Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Matches.Groups[1].Value

    If ($Queued -gt 100 )
    {
        $MailArgs = @{
            'To'          = 'ab2112@test.com'
            'From'        = 'netbackup@test.com'
            'Subject'     = 'Over 100 Queued Jobs!'
            'Attachments' = $Output
            'Body'        = 'Check Environment'

            'SmtpServer' = 'smtp.us.test.com'
        }

        Send-MailMessage @MailArgs
    }
}
Else
{
    $MailArgs = @{
        'To'          = 'ab2112@test.com'
        'From'        = 'netbackup@test.com'
        'Subject'     = 'No output found!'
       #'Attachments' = $Output
        'Body'        = 'Check Environment'

        'SmtpServer' = 'smtp.us.test.com'
    }

    Send-MailMessage @MailArgs
}
```

I would suspect the data simply is not there when the cmdlet runs, as the regex, the resulting members and the methods invoked all work fine if you're testing against a file with that data in it.

If the data is simply not there, replace this:

```
.\bpdbjobs -summary -L > $Output
```

With this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath .\bpdbjobs -ArgumentList "-summary","-L","> $Output" -Wait
```

Alternatively, if the resulting members and methods are not working, you could try this:

```
$Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Line.Split(" ")[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the line of code, using matches instead of match:

```
(Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: I was using matches just a typo when typing it over here. Same error

Comment: `$Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Matches.Groups[1].Value` Returns` `Cannot index into a null array.
At line:6 char:83
+ $Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Matches.Groups[ <<<< 1].Value
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

Comment: @AB2112 `$queued` looks like its a string not an integer. `[int]$queued -gt 100` might fair better

Comment: Same error...I think it has to do with the expression commands

Comment: I think about the output of the command bpdbjobs. Can you try to save the output info in a text file and run the Select-String cmdlet to check if the error is the same?